# Слетел перевод фразы уведомления, которая появляется при попытке отправить ответ, когда ваши ответы низкокачественны

Tags: дефект, локализация, ответы, блокировка, запрет-публикаций

Когда меня заблокировали, пропала возможность публиковать ответы. В ответах, при попытке прислать вопрос вылезало уведомление, в котором слетел перевод фразы:

[image: Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more.]

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See [the Help Center](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) to learn more.

Если посетить справку, то там можно увидеть уже переведённый текст уведомления (поэтому я и подумал, что перевод слетел):

> С этой учетной записи больше не принимаются ответы. Более подробную информацию см. в разделе ["Справка"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

Считаю подобный перевод не совсем близким к оригиналу и раз у нас появился шанс, можно попытаться сделать более точный перевод, я предлагаю вот такой:

> Простите, мы больше не принимаем ответов от вашего аккаунта, так как большинство из ваших ответов требуют улучшения или недостаточны для ответа на вопрос. Посетите ["Справку"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans), чтобы узнать больше.

Считаете ли вы что стоит оставить старый перевод? Если нет, то как вы бы перевели эту фразу (также как я, или как-нибудь иначе)? Если да, то почему?

Comment: По возможности предлагайте ваши переводы сразу в [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/). Должно быть всем удобнее.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо, в следующий раз буду публиковать предложение перевода там.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18150
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18401

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.4.21.43403.